# Rename Laravel Collection Key

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I have a set of data dictionary `$dataDictCollection`

```
"column_a" => "Column A",
"column_b" => "Column B",
"column_c" => "Column C",
"column_d" => "Column D",
"column_e" => "Column E",
```

I have another set of result `$resultCollection`

```
[{
    "column_a" => "value 100",
    "column_b" => "value 200",
    "column_c" => "value 300",
    "column_d" => "value 400",
    "column_e" => "value 500",
},{
    "column_a" => "value 110",
    "column_b" => "value 220",
    "column_c" => "value 330",
    "column_d" => "value 440",
    "column_e" => "value 550",
}]
```

In the result, I'd like to have the data dictionary's value as the result's key. For example:

```
"Column A" => "value 100",
"Column B" => "value 200",
"Column C" => "value 300",
"Column D" => "value 400",
"Column E" => "value 500",
```

Do note that my number of columns are A LOT, I could not specify the key name like below.

```
return $data['Column A'] = 'value 100';
```

I tried `mapWithKeys`, `keyBy` but I don't know how to return my desire result.

I tried

```
return collect($resultCollection)->map(function ($result) use ($dataDictCollection) {
    return collect($dataDictCollection)->map(function ($dataDic) use ($result) {
        $name[$dataDic] = $result[$dataDic];
        return $name;
    });
});
```

But it returns this :(

```
"column_a": {
    "Column A": "value 100"
},
"column_b": {
    "Column B": "value 200"
},
```

Another attempt

```
return collect($resultCollection)->map(function ($result) use ($dataDictCollection) {
    return collect($result)->combine($dataDictCollection);
})->values();
```

but it returns like this, reversed and not returning the full data dictionary.

```
[{
    "value 100" => "Column A",
    "value 200" => "Column B",
    "value 300" => "Column C",
},{
    "value 110" => "Column A",
    "value 220" => "Column B",
    "value 330" => "Column C",
}]
```

Comment: Have you tried `$name= $deal[$dataDic];` this one

Comment: @A.ANoman i got `Illegal offset type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [combine](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-combine) method of collection

```
$resultCollection = collect([
    "column_a" => "Column A",
    "column_b" => "Column B",
    "column_c" => "Column C",
    "column_d" => "Column D",
    "column_e" => "Column E",
])->sortKeys();

$dataDictCollection = collect([[
    "column_a" => "value 100",
    "column_b" => "value 200",
    "column_c" => "value 300",
    "column_d" => "value 400",
    "column_e" => "value 500",
], [
    "column_a" => "value 110",
    "column_b" => "value 220",
    "column_c" => "value 330",
    "column_d" => "value 440",
    "column_e" => "value 550",
]]);

$result = collect();
$dataDictCollection->each(function ($item, $key) use ($result, $resultCollection) {
    $result->push($resultCollection->combine(collect($item)->sortKeys())->all());
});

dd($result->all());
```

Comment: i got an error: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements. because I will have multiple sets of $resultCollection and only 1 set of $dateDictCollection.

Comment: Give some realtime data.

Comment: added in the ques, pls see `$resultCollection `

Comment: amazing!! you got it what i want. thank you so much. :)